# how to use sort, cut, and unique commands in pipe

Tags: linux

I was wondering how do you use the cut, sort, and uniq commands in a pipeline and give a command line that indicates how many users are using each of the shells mentioned in /etc/passwd?
i'm not sure if this is right but

```
cut -f1 -d':' /etc/passwd | sort -n | uniq
```

?

Comment: A. isn't the shell the last arg in `/etc/passwd`? (I'm in a hurry) maybe `cut -d: -f8`. . The `-n` opt for sort means sort values a **numbers**, remove that. C. `uniq -c` may be what you want. D. Learn to debug shell pipe-lines by incrementally adding stages, after examining the output of an partial pipeline. (You may need to add `|head -5`, or `tail -5` to reduce the output while in the early part of the pipeline, before your output gets reduced to a manageable size). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter It's the seventh field (`cut -d: -f7`).  On my OSX box, there are some lines with comments which need to be removed as well.  `cut -s -d: -f7` does that nicely, but somewhat haphazardly.

Comment: yeah i fixed it, forgot to respond but thanks for all the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summarizing the answers excruciatingly hidden in comments:*

You were close, only

- as tripleee noticed, the shell is in the seventh field
- as shellter noticed, since the shells are not numbers, `-n` is useless
- as shellter noticed, for the counting, there's `uniq -c`

That gives

```
cut -f7 -d: /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c
```